# Linked List Push Function

Tags: c, list, stack, push

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct stackNode
{
    int data;
    struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};


void instructions()
{
    printf("[1]Push a value on the stack\n");
    printf("[2]Pop a value off the stack\n");
    printf("[3]Display the whole stack\n");
    printf("[4]Exit");
} 

void push(struct stackPtr *topPtr, int info)
{
    struct stackPtr *newPtr;
    newPtr= malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
    if(newPtr !=NULL)
    {
        newPtr->data = info;
        newPtr->nextPtr=*topPtr;
        *topPtr=newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d not inserted no memory available");
    }

int main()
{
    struct StackNodePtr *stackPtr;
    stackPtr = NULL;
    int choice, value;
    do
    {   
        instructions();
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            printf("Enter  a value for the stack");     
        }             
        if(choice == 2)
        {
            printf(" "); 
        }       
        if(choice == 3)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(choice == 4 )
        {
            printf("bye!");
            return 0;
        }
    } while(choice !=4);
    system("pause");
}
```

I made a function push for my linked list and stack code but the thing is it's not working there are Enormous errors in the function push what's wrong with it? it's not allowing the malloc to be used why is that?

Comment: OMG, this is like the sixth question about pretty much the same thing ... You're really grinding on that list, aren't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [typedef and linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552394/typedef-and-linked-list)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
struct stackNode { int data; struct stackNode *nextPtr; };

int main() { struct stackNode * stackPtr = NULL; }
```

Comment: is this the same as this
?? struct stackNode *stackPtr;

stackPtr = NULL;??

Comment: It is, but I prefer the style in my answer as I like to explicitly initialize my definitions.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct stackNode
{
   int data;
   struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

int main()
{
    struct stackNode *stackPtr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
// just precede the struct type with ... struct
struct stackNode* stackPtr = NULL;
```

Happy coding.

Comment: how about this? can anyone transcribe this too? typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;

Comment: Just take them out? If they aren't being used, they aren't being used.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

is wrong by the way. Your typedefs should be:

```
typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode* StackNodePtr;
```

No idea why you're against using `typedef` - it tends to make the code a lot more readable.

Comment: I just want to keep it simple and it confuses me a lot 
 ooppp sorry how do I fix this ?? typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef StackNode* StackNodePtr; without any typdefs?

Comment: @Kyel: I think the other answers from @John Källén, @pst and @0verbose already show you how to write your code without `typedef` - if that is not what you want then you need to reword your question.

Comment: soo to sum it all up, it's only like that??