# List of a List in C

Tags: c, list, memory

I am trying to dynamically allocate list of pointers to pointers of structs which each contain a list of structs with the following definition:

```
struct node {
     char *text;
     struct node  *next; };
```

I am also using a typedef:

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

I am creating a list of nodes to hold each list by declaring the following:

```
Node **list;
list = (struct node**) malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * arraySize);
```

At each of the nodes of `list` I will have another list which I am creating as follows:

```
list[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * subArraySize);
```

I have several questions:

1. Is this the correct implementation for such a problem?
2. How can I access the `text` data member of the first node of each list within the larger list?

If my question is vague please let me know. My confusion on this topic makes it difficult to word my question properly.

Comment: Your typedef serves no purpose. You use the word "list" (and the variable name `list`) to refer to both lists and arrays. You are attempting to use a tower of indirection when it is not clear that you have any layer working correctly. You must start with simple problems and work up to the complex ones, or you are sure to fail.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build an array containing pointers to the heads of several linked lists, right? The second part, `list[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * subArraySize);`, is kind of misguided because you are allocated a contiguous block of memory for several `node`s ahead of time, whereas normally you would probably allocate memory for each node as it's created, or at least you wouldn't use this structure which is pretty strictly a 2d array.

Comment: The secondary malloc makes no sense if you are trying to make a dynamic array of pointers to linked lists. The latter is a *linked list* and as such needs no vector allocation (assuming that `next` member isn't just there for window dressing or other nefarious purposes). That said, what is the problem you're *really* trying to solve, a hash table with collision chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your memory is allocated and filled up correctly, you'd access the `text` data member of the first node of each `node*` array within the larger `node**` array via:

```
list[i]->text
```

But, to answer your question about the implementation being correct, it's not really. You'd probably be happier doing this:

```
struct node **list;
list = (struct node**) calloc(sizeof(struct node*) * arraySize);
for (int i=0; i<arraySize; ++i) {
    list[i] = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list[i]->text = ""; // or whatever you want to start with
    list[i]->next = NULL;
}
```

This creates a `node**` array (called `list`, since you wanted to call it that, but I would call it something else indicates it's an array of `node`-based linked lists), then instantiates a block of memory for each head `node` so that `list` is full of valid `node*`s and you can start working with them.

When you go to append something to each of your linked lists, you'd do something like this (this appends to the end, it's up to you to implement insertion based on comparing values if you want sorted data, etc.):

```
int i = index_where_you_want_to_insert;
struct node *currNode = list[i];
struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->text = ""; // or whatever you want to start with
newNode->next = NULL;
while(currNode->next != NULL) {
    currNode = currNode->next;
}
currNode->next = newNode;
```

It may also help you to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552394/typedef-and-linked-list) about using `typedef` with linked lists.

If I've made any syntactic or semantic errors in my code, I apologize, it's been a while since I wrote C and I may be rusty with how to refer to `struct`s. I welcome corrections.